# How to perform joins in mongodb effectively using $match

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

How do you perform joins in mongodb? If I join two or more collections, it is not effective and joining properly, even though I have used `$match`.

Here is the code I've tried:

```
db.tasks.aggregate([{"$match":{"$and":[{"super_user_id":"5dad7e6d937e2929d3930a45","is_deleted":0}]}},{"$lookup":{"from":"projects","localField":"projects._id","foreignField":"tasks.project_id","as":"pro"}},{"$unwind":"$pro"},{"$project":{"task_name":1,"project_id":"$pro._id","project_name":"$pro.project_name"}},{"$group":{"_id":{"task_name":"$task_name","taskId":"$_id","project_name":"$project_name","project_id":"$project_id"}}}])
```

getting output as:

```
{ "_id" : { "task_name" : "very second task", "taskId" : ObjectId("5dcbb770937e29163cfed455"), "project_name" : "test", "project_id" : ObjectId("5dc9ab54937e292110e2ad17") } }
{ "_id" : { "task_name" : "very second task", "taskId" : ObjectId("5dcbb770937e29163cfed455"), "project_name" : "monday", "project_id" : ObjectId("5dc91fc9937e2937e0407647") } }
{ "_id" : { "task_name" : "very second task", "taskId" : ObjectId("5dcbb770937e29163cfed455"), "project_name" : "nnnn", "project_id" : ObjectId("5dc90f67937e2924d82087fb") } }
{ "_id" : { "task_name" : "very second task", "taskId" : ObjectId("5dcbb770937e29163cfed455"), "project_name" : "vvv", "project_id" : ObjectId("5dc90ea6937e2924d82087fa") } }
```

Let me elaborate the issue:

For the same `task_name` is it mapping with all existing projects

Comment: Can you add example data for tasks collection?

Comment: you can use multiple time $lookup in aggregate to join two or more collection. and, please provide sample data of which you are trying to aggregate on.

Comment: db.tasks.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5db68df2937e291a8d539e74"),
        "project_id" : "5db68d59937e291a8d539e73",
        "task_name" : "stock task1",
        "user_id" : "5db0040b937e2912c22a8d84",
        "assinged" : "string",
        "super_user_id" : "5daee0eb937e2949f3eefdb0",
        "task_description" : "string",
        "file_path" : "string",
        "is_group" : 0,
        "group_id" : "string",
        "is_done" : "1",
        "is_dependent" : 0,
        "is_bug" : 0,
        "is_cr" : 0
        
} @SuleymanSah

Comment: please can anyone help me out with this